# How to update detailView using a popover

Tags: xcode, ios, ipad, uitableview

I have a `TableViewController` which is represented by a popover, that is displayed by selecting a bar button item on a tool bar.  I'm having a problem however that when I select an item from the table in the popover it doesn't update the view (`affirmaPDFViewController`)

Here is the `DidSelectRowAtIndex` method for my `PDFTableController` (the popover):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

affirmaPDFViewController.detailItem = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [listOfPDF objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
affirmaPDFViewController.i = indexPath.row;
NSLog(@"%d", indexPath.row);
NSLog(@"%@", [listOfPDF objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
NSLog(@"%d", affirmaPDFViewController.i);
NSLog(@"%@", affirmaPDFViewController.detailItem);
}
```

Here the indexPath.row and the objectAtIndex:indexPath.row all return the correct values.  However when I assign the variables from `affirmaPDFViewController` to those values they just return 0 and null.

I've been told it is because I haven't created an instance of `affirmaPDFViewController`. However, I'm not sure how to create such an instance.  What code would I put in this method to get this to work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    affirmaPDFViewController = [[NameOfClassGoesHere alloc] initWithNibName:@"NibNameGoesHere" bundle:nil]; 

}
```

Comment: which class? the table class which represents the popover? or the view controller which represents the detail view?

Comment: Class of affirmaPDFViewController